# Developing probability theory from measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

Last quarter I took a course in measure theory, following most of the first chapters of Folland's "Real Analysis" book, so the course covered Caratheodory's theorem, the construction of the Lebesgue measure on the real line and on $\mathbb{R}^d$, Lebesgue-integration and $L_p$-spaces. Now I'm starting to study probability theory developed from this toolbox of measure theory, and I have (some) doubts about the subject:

1) the construction of a probability measure doesn't follow *exactly* the same way that Lebesgue's measure were constructed on the real line, more specifically using this result:

"Given a premeasure $\mu_0$ defined on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then the function $\mu^{\ast}$ defined as

$$\mu^{\ast}(A) = \inf \bigg\{  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu_0 (A_n) \ | A_n \in \mathcal{A}, A \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n  \bigg\} \ ,$$

is an exterior measure", and so we use Caratheodory's theorem for extending this measure for the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$? What's the big deal that every book needs to do it *again* if it is an straight application of a result in measure theory?

2) What are some *good* references that deals with this subject assuming knowledge from measure theory and don't try to develop measure theory again just for constructing a probability measure? I looked at Klenke's book, and most of the classics and they are a mess of notation, confusing text and simply bad writing. Don't get me wrong, all this books certainly have all their results right and probably don't make great mistakes, but their writing is TERRIBLE. I never saw an area of mathematics with so many badly written books as probability theory; they don't agree with each other's notations, have the most confusing and illogical development ever and just feels like a reunion of scattered results I could find on wikipedia. But I'm sure there is a good book on this out there.

Comment: I went from Rudin to probability measures, so it may have been slightly easier given that there were numerous practice problems in terms of finite measures, but **even still** I personally prefer seeing the basics in the new notation. You also may have skipped or not concentrated on some measure theory concepts that are important in probability theory, like atoms or relationships between many types of convergence. Either way, probability theory books will either teach measures or assume they're known, and in the latter case they'll likely assume all concepts are understood also.

Comment: But I one hundred percent agree with annoyance at notation. But it drives home the point, for instance Jensen's inequality looks different in terms of expectation notation than the $L^2$ Jensen's. It might just be worth following an author-you-like's notation. Personally, I'd sit there with Rudin and Royden on one side of me and Rosenthal's "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory" on the other.

Comment: Please give an example of "TERRIBLE writing" and/or "illogical development". This will help to avoid "bad" references.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several suggestions, at least one of which is what you asked for. :)

Durrett's recent book is solid, modern, and was used by Terry Tao for a class recently.

Did you know that Kolmogorov is an outstanding writer? I have learned a great deal from his book he wrote with Fomin (Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis). His original book where he lays out how to do probability theory with measure theory is also on Amazon as a cheap reprint. Even if it's outdated, it could be worth your time.

Edward Nelson has a short and beautiful book called Radically Elementary Probability Theory that avoids measure theory entirely. :) Likewise, if you are interested in yet another unconventional book in this general area by an incredibly wise man and clear writer, Jaynes' Probability Theory: the Logic of Science is a monument.